# Google maps sdk ios search markers

Tags: google-maps, search, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am playing with the google maps sdk for ios.
I was wondering if it's possible to add an search function where you can search for your markers?
Or do i need to use the google places api?

Comment: Please? somebody? who can answer this question!?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Google Places API to make HTTP requests from your app. You should request a JSON file. Then you'll need to parse the response, and use it to add markers to a GMSMapView.

Update:

You could also use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) for iOS

Comment: allright i have googled about it and i came up with this tutorial link:http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit  so what i think is to implement this in my viewController.m https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere or am i wrong?